# CloudKit from Yosemite

Tags: cloudkit, osx-yosemite

I'm considering CloudKit for my iOS application where there is a set of public data that everyone needs.  A couple times a week a new record is pushed into the public dataset.  The current version of the app pings my webserver to download those records.  I'd instead rather have my server simply write the record into the public database and then the iOS app can use subscriptions to know when there's a new entry.

From what I'm seeing though I'm not sure if this is possible.  If I make a Mac based app, for example, how do I specify the entitlements like I do on the iOS app?  I've also seen some thing that make me believe it would only work if that mac app was published to the app store, which wouldn't make sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Gargoyle,

Your question has made very clear that if you want to use cloudkit for your OSX app you need to  be not only a registered iOS developer (paying your 99$ a year) but also a mac developer (paying also 99$ for the mac developer program).

I did try to share some data between OSX and iOS app but wasn't able to activate the capabilities in the mac app project it requests the mac developer id

Hope this helps!